# mpmovieplayer - Need to know when the video has finished loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am playing a video with mpmovieplayer, but I need to know when the video has loaded completely so I can turn off the network activity indicator. is there a notification that would tell me when the video is completely loaded?

I was thinking the four load states would help:

- MPMovieLoadStateUnknown
- MPMovieLoadStatePlayable
- MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK
- MPMovieLoadStateStalled

I tried the playthroughok load state but that doesn't tell me when the video is completely loaded.

Here is some of my .m code for my video player:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:self.videoitem];

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];


self.moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];     
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would turn off the indicator as soon as it starts playing. What's the user waiting on at that point? Register for notifications and show the indicator whenever it's stalled and hide when it's playing.

Comment: I thought the network indicator had to be on whenever you are pulling any data. is that not the case? if not, thats awesome i can just show it like you said when it's stalled, then hide it again.